# Proper cellForRowAtIndexPath cell return in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit

So I have started creating a UITableView with multiple prototype cells. I currently have the below code setup, which works fine

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: UITableViewCell?

    if indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) - 1 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddSetCell")
    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SetCell") as! SetTableViewCell
    }

    return cell!
}
```

I have learned to avoid using `!` as much as possible when dealing with optionals. However, I also don't like creating an `if let` statement a thousand times. In theory, `cell` should never be `nil` because 
my code only allows `cell` to be one of the identifiers above. However it still makes me nervous in terms of bad practice.

If I do `var cell = UITableViewCell`, I have to unwrap both of the calls to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` or XCode gets mad at me.

Which is the best approach for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that

```
func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

is preferred over

```
func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell?
```

because – according to the documentation –

> This method uses the index path to perform additional configuration based on the cell’s position in the table view.

and because it returns a *non-optional* `UITableViewCell`.

If you just want to return one of the two possible prototype cells
then you don't need to cast at all.

But there is no need to make `cell` an optional. You can even 
declare it as a *constant,* this allows the compiler to verify that it is assigned a value exactly once
on each code path.

```
let cell: UITableViewCell
if condition {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddSetCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
} else {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SetCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
}
// ... set up common properties ...
return cell
```

If you want to assign specific properties to the different cell types
then you need to cast to the respective type.
Since  you define the  custom class `SetTableViewCell` for the prototype cell with identifier "SetCell" in the Storyboard,

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SetCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

is *guaranteed* to return an instance of `SetTableViewCell`, either by
re-using a cell or by instantiating a new one from the prototype.
This is one of the legitimate use-cases of the
forced cast operator `as!`. Or to put it differently: The cast can only
fail if you did not define the prototype cell correctly. That would be
a *programming error* and should be detected early.

```
let cell: UITableViewCell
if condition {
    let aCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddSetCell") as! AddTableViewCell
    // ... set up specific properties ...
    cell = aCell
} else {
    let sCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SetCell") as! SetTableViewCell
    // ... set up specific properties ...
    cell = sCell
}
// ... set up common properties ...
return cell
```

or alternatively with "early return":

```
if condition {
    let aCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddSetCell") as! AddTableViewCell
    // ... set up properties ...
    return aCell
} else {
    let sCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SetCell") as! SetTableViewCell
    // ... set up properties ...
    return sCell
}
```

that is a matter of personal choice.

Finally, if you write your condition as

```
indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section) - 1
```

then it will work for all sections, not only the first one.

Comment: I saw a big problem in this approach. Let say in any case xib file missing or something then this method will return an empty cell as the UITableViewCell. If that so user will see nothing and there is no way us as developer to get notified about it. If we didn't return empty cell and let application to crash in any case xib is missing at least we can get notified that something is wrong on our application.

Comment: @TharinduKetipearachchi: But `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(...) as! AddTableViewCell` *does* crash if the the XIB file is missing, because of the forced cast.

Comment: @TharinduKetipearachchi: That's why I wrote “This is one of the legitimate use-cases of the forced cast operator” and “The cast can only fail if you did not define the prototype cell correctly.”

Comment: I'm also finding a legitimate solution for this. Seems like different devs have different idea on this. Do you know any place where we can find Apple's guideline to doing this? Because some company has failed my interview assignment due to this problem